# Right way to update the data in a table?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I need add three columns in a pandas dataframe, from existing data.

```
df
>>
    n    a     b
0   3  1.2   1.4
1   2  2.8   3.8
2   3  2.3   2.0
3   3  1.7   5.7
4   2  6.9   4.9
5   1  3.9  19.0
6   9  2.3   8.3
7   5  8.5   3.1
8  18  6.7   7.0
9  10  5.6   6.4
```

I have done the following

```
import pandas
import numpy
def add_tests(add_df):
    new_tests = """
        (a+b)/n
        (a*b)/n
        ((a+b)/n)**-1
    """.split()
    rows = add_df.shape[0]
    cols = len(new_tests)
    U = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.empty([rows, cols]), columns=new_tests)
    add_df = pandas.concat([df, U], axis=1)
    for i, row in add_df.iterrows():
        # 1) good calculation:
        add_df['(a+b)/n'].loc[i] = (add_df['a'].loc[i] + add_df['b'].loc[i])/ add_df['n'].loc[i]
        # 2) good calculation (Both ways):
        add_df['(a*b)/n'].loc[i] = (row['a'] * row['b'])/ row['n']
        # 3) bad calculation
        add_df['((a+b)/n)**-1'].loc[i] = row['(a+b)/n'] ** -1
        pass
    return add_df
```

I get the next warning message:

```
df = add_tests(df)
df
>>
```

> C:...\pandas\core\indexing.py:141: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
>   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

```
    n    a     b    (a+b)/n    (a*b)/n  ((a+b)/n)**-1
0   3  1.2   1.4   0.866667   0.560000       0.833333
1   2  2.8   3.8   3.300000   5.320000       0.588235
2   3  2.3   2.0   1.433333   1.533333       0.434783
3   3  1.7   5.7   2.466667   3.230000       0.178571
4   2  6.9   4.9   5.900000  16.905000       0.500000
5   1  3.9  19.0  22.900000  74.100000       0.052632
6   9  2.3   8.3   1.177778   2.121111       0.142857
7   5  8.5   3.1   2.320000   5.270000       0.263158
8  18  6.7   7.0   0.761111   2.605556       0.111111
9  10  5.6   6.4   1.200000   3.584000       0.666667
```

Obviously step 3 does not work properly ...
How to do it the right way?

Comment: Seem to have done it very differently for 1) and 2), why did you do the calculations in such a different way for 3)? Do it the same way, breaking it up like that, and I bet it'll work.

Comment: Using any of the three ways, i get the warning message. Additionally: `0.866667 ** - 1 = 1.1538457100593422`

Comment: I have already edited the `add_df ['((a + b) / n) ** - 1']. Loc [i]`, I had forgotten the `loc`. Sorry u_u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fun with `eval`**

- define tuples of temporary column names with formulas
- create a `\n` separated string of formulas to pass to `eval`
- use dictionary to make formulas into column names

---

```
ftups = [('aa', '(a+b)/n'), ('bb', '(a*b)/n'), ('cc', '((a+b)/n)**-1')]
forms = '\n'.join([' = '.join(tup) for tup in ftups])
fdict = dict(ftups)

df.eval(forms, inplace=False).rename(columns=fdict)

    n    a     b    (a+b)/n    (a*b)/n  ((a+b)/n)**-1
0   3  1.2   1.4   0.866667   0.560000       1.153846
1   2  2.8   3.8   3.300000   5.320000       0.303030
2   3  2.3   2.0   1.433333   1.533333       0.697674
3   3  1.7   5.7   2.466667   3.230000       0.405405
4   2  6.9   4.9   5.900000  16.905000       0.169492
5   1  3.9  19.0  22.900000  74.100000       0.043668
6   9  2.3   8.3   1.177778   2.121111       0.849057
7   5  8.5   3.1   2.320000   5.270000       0.431034
8  18  6.7   7.0   0.761111   2.605556       1.313869
9  10  5.6   6.4   1.200000   3.584000       0.833333
```

Comment: woow!! ... Excellent!! how would you do it in the following case? ... df['RSS'].loc[i] = self._apply_RSS_(self.x_predictors[df['vars']], self.target). Where vars are different combinations of columns that I need to use. _apply_RSS_ finds the prediction and then the RSS. It works correctly with loc, but returns the warning message. self.x_predictors It's all the numeric table. In other words, I need to update a column first, then I can use your recommendation ...

Comment: `def _apply_rss_():
            rss = 0.0
            rss = stats.scores.RSS(
                self.y_exp, redux_y_pred,)
            return rss`